# Nginx: directly return $remote_addr in text/plain

Tags: networking, nginx

It may sound like a code golf question, but what is the simplest / lightest way to return `$remote_addr` in `text/plain`?

So, it should return several bytes of the IP address in a plain text.

```
216.58.221.164
```

Use case: An API to learn the client's own external (NAT), global IP address.

Is it possible to do it with Nginx alone and without any backends? If so, how?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
location /remote_addr {
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 "$remote_addr\n";
}
```

The above should be added to the `server` block of your `nginx.conf`.

No need to use any 3rd party module (echo, lua etc.)

Comment: Perfect, that's what I wanted exactly. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach you can use to consider proxied connections:

```
# Map IP address to variable
map ":$http_x_forwarded_for" $IP_ADDR {
    ":" $remote_addr; # Forwarded for not set
    default $http_x_forwarded_for; # Forwarded for is set
}

server {
    ...

    location / {
        default_type text/plain;
        return 200 "$IP_ADDR";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngx_echo`:

```
location /ip {
    default_type  text/plain;
    echo $remote_addr;
}
```

Use [ngx_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule):

```
location /b {
    default_type  text/plain;
    content_by_lua '
        ngx.say(ngx.var.remote_addr)
    ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I made a practice always to add ip.example.com to most of my servers with the following configuration:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ cat ip
server {
    server_name ip.*;

    root       /dev/null;
    access_log /dev/null;
    error_log  /dev/null;

    location / {
        default_type text/plain;
        return 200 "$remote_addr\n";
    }
}
```

It's really helpful for checking VPN, networks, remote accesses, scripting, etc... You can use it in the browser directly or curl in cli...